# “Scalable JavaScript Application Architecture” and module access

Tags: javascript

I am building a large javascript application and I decided to use Nicholas Zakas' scalable application architecture design: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vXjVFPosQHw

According to his system, modules are self-encapsulated and do not know about each other, but during runtime when all documents have loaded, I am able to add a getElementById() in one of the modules to access another modules div and modify it directly.

Are there any workarounds to prevent this?

Comment: As far as I know there are no workarounds for this. You just shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to prevent people of doing this in the development phase - not in the runtime. You can do this kind of prevention using tools like Babel to transpile ES6 modules or TypeScript. The point is that during the runtime environment you can't isolate the DOM. You can move this one step back and have compiled environment that will prevent the developers from doing these kind of mistakes/workarounds.